# Publish / unpublish media items in the media library

Tags: media, media-library

I'm wondering if / how I might publish and unpublish specific media library items without deleting them, using plugins and/or theme code.

My use case is that I am planning a site where pages will dynamically show collections of media, based on custom fields set on the media items. We will also allow site visitors to upload media themselves, and we want a screening step for an editor to publish media items before they go live on the site.

I have come across the [Media Library Assistant plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/), and it looks as though this might be achieved by setting custom fields to stand in for something like "status" = "published" or "draft".

However, is there another approach that is more clear to editors, similar to setting status on pages and posts?

Comment: use wordpress rest api

Comment: @shadi Thanks. Can you provide more detail on how to go about that approach?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this through js or php?

Comment: @shadi I would imagine php would be a bit better performing, but whichever is more sensible for this use case.